# how to flatten complex nested json using spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a code which flattens json data properly but its little slow as data is complex(input is taken as dict), but I want a similar code which works on spark dataframe.

```
#Flattening code
from functools import (partial,
                       singledispatch)
from itertools import chain
from typing import (Dict,
                    List,
                    TypeVar)

Serializable = TypeVar('Serializable', None, int, bool, float, str,
                       dict, list, tuple)
Array = List[Serializable]
Object = Dict[str, Serializable]


def flatten(object_: Object,
            *,
            path_separator: str = '.') -> Array[Object]:
    """
    Flattens given JSON object into list of objects with non-nested values.

    >>> flatten({'a': 1})
    [{'a': 1}]
    >>> flatten({'a': [1, 2]})
    [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
    >>> flatten({'a': {'b': None}})
    [{'a.b': None}]
    >>> flatten({'a': [1, 2], 'b': []})
    [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
    """
    keys = set(object_)
    result = [dict(object_)]
    while keys:
        key = keys.pop()
        new_result = []
        for index, record in enumerate(result):
            try:
                value = record[key]
            except KeyError:
                new_result.append(record)
            else:
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    del record[key]
                    new_value = flatten_nested_objects(
                            value,
                            prefix=key + path_separator,
                            path_separator=path_separator
                    )
                    keys.update(new_value.keys())
                    new_result.append({**new_value, **record})
                elif isinstance(value, list):
                    del record[key]
                    new_records = [
                        flatten_nested_objects(sub_value,
                                               prefix=key + path_separator,
                                               path_separator=path_separator)
                        for sub_value in value
                    ]
                    keys.update(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.keys,
                                                        new_records)))
                    if new_records:
                        new_result.extend({**new_record, **record}
                                          for new_record in new_records)
                    else:
                        new_result.append(record)
                else:
                    new_result.append(record)
        result = new_result
    return result


@singledispatch
def flatten_nested_objects(object_: Serializable,
                           *,
                           prefix: str = '',
                           path_separator: str) -> Object:
    return {prefix[:-len(path_separator)]: object_}


@flatten_nested_objects.register(dict)
def _(object_: Object,
      *,
      prefix: str = '',
      path_separator: str) -> Object:
    result = dict(object_)
    for key in list(result):
        result.update(flatten_nested_objects(result.pop(key),
                                             prefix=(prefix + key
                                                     + path_separator),
                                             path_separator=path_separator))
    return result


@flatten_nested_objects.register(list)
def _(object_: Array,
      *,
      prefix: str = '',
      path_separator: str) -> Object:
    return {prefix[:-len(path_separator)]: list(map(partial(
            flatten_nested_objects,
            path_separator=path_separator),
            object_))}
```

how to perform similar operation with spark dataframe to handle any kind of structure and flatten to leaf level.

similar code which works on spark dataframe and flatten properly and handles any complex types

Comment: any code snippet which works on spark dataframe is helpful!!